# How do I use wine after downloading bluestack to my laptop?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I would like to see if bluestack is compatible. I have downloaded the program WINE and I have downloaded the program bluestack.

How do I install bluestack through WINE?

Answer (score 1):

Bluestacks App Player is a compatibility layer and a emulator that enables a Windows PC install and execute Android programs and integrate them on Windows Desktop without need of the Android SDK or a virtual machine.

You can check the [Wine homepage](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13717) and see that all versions of bluestack will not work under Wine.

<sup>Source:[Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13717)</sup>